# Polymer and http requests

Tags: angularjs, polymer

Recently I have heard about **Polymer** as a new way of building web applications, so let say I am very new to the field and the first thing I saw is the syntax of importing Polymer elements inside the page using a link tag.

In the Polymer example pages, some Polymers import other polymers that import other polymers ...

Isn't this a bit failing the rule of every well developed web applications that says every page should reduce the number of http requests as to increase the pages' loading ?

Comment: As with all external includes (CSS, Javascript etc. etc.), you can inline and/or compact all those external files into a single resource. You're not required to serve it all in separate files.

Comment: The browser is smart enough to determine if an imported resource has already been loaded. Also when HTTP/2 becomes the norm, combining all files as one giant resource would actually become the antipattern as opposed to serving them separately.

Answer (score 0):

As stated correctly in Neil John Ramals answer:

> The browser is smart enough to determine if an imported resource has already been loaded. Also when HTTP/2 becomes the norm, combining all files as one giant resource would actually become the antipattern as opposed to serving them separately.

You can use a command-line tool like [Polymer CLI](https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-cli) to optimize a build for production.

There is also a convenience method for importing an HTML document imperatively: [Polymer.Base.importHref](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/api/Polymer.Base#method-importHref)